# Python - cannot access class property

Tags: python, class

I'm writing a class to access a mySQL db from python.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import configparser

class db():

    def __init__(self):

        try:
            self.handler = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user=user, passwd=passwd, db=dbname)
            self.cur = self.handler.cursor()
        except:
            print "Couldn't connect to db"


    def query(self, query):

        self.lastQuery = query
        self.res = self.cur.execute(query)

    def close(self):

        self.handler.close()
```

When I'm trying to call the class, it give me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "db.class.py", line 6, in <module>
  class db():
File "db.class.py", line 25, in db
  self.res = self.cur.execute(query)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I've been searching and commonly there's people that forget to define the method with 'self' as an argument. But I'm including it.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I checked whitespaces and tabs and that is not the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has mixed tabs and spaces, causing Python to get confused about what statements are at what indentation level. The assignment to `self.res` has ended up at class level, outside of the method it was intended to be a part of.

Stop mixing tabs and spaces. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor to make the problem more visible, and consider running Python with the `-tt` flag to give an error on ambiguous mixing of tabs and spaces.

Comment: I'm preety sure whitespaces are not the problem.

Comment: @Ign: The edit view clearly shows tabs and spaces mixed in such a way that they would cause this error, and the traceback clearly shows that the `self.res` assignment is outside of any method. Are you sure you know what to look for? If you only checked the indentation of the rendered version of your question, be aware that the markdown rendering converts tabs to spaces. Check your actual source file.